# How to let a grids image components go to the next line instead of "overlapping" each other when zooming in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a material-ui Grid component to display 5 images across the screen. However, when zooming in they overlap each other instead of going to the next line.

Instead of displaying maybe 2 images per row they all just stay as 5 images on one row and bunched up together and crossing over each other

```
        <Grid justify="space-around"
            alignItems="flex-end"
            container
            maxWidth="xl"
            style={{ paddingLeft: '4.5%', paddingTop: '2%' }}>
            <Grid item xs={3} sm={2}  >
                <img src={fundraiserIcon} alt="" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3} sm={2} >
                <img src={statisticsIcon} alt="" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3} sm={2} >
                <img src={speechBubble} alt="" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3} sm={2}  >
                <img src={globeIcon} alt="" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3} sm={2} >
                <img src={boxesHome} alt="" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```